# Does rearrangement occur in schmidt reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds, carbocation, rearrangements

I recently read about schmidt reaction in which a carboxylic acid is converted to an amine. While forming this, acyl carbocation $(\ce{RCO+})$ is formed, so does rearrangement takes place or reaction takes place without any rearrangement?

Comment: I am not sure where you read this( you have to show effort and give citations while asking questions) but schmidt reaction proceeds with hydrazoic acid forming geminal diol intermediate which undergoes wolff rearrangement and subsequent hydrolysis to give amine, not amide.

Comment: Take a look at this  https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/schmidt-reaction.shtm

Comment: Oh sorry it’s amine only I didn’t see that I wrote amide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As napstablook pointed out in the comment section, I didn't understand where you got this erronous information about Schmidt reaction. For example, it definitely didn't give a amide with the reaction with carboxylic acid. The product is a corresponding amine with one less carbon.

Basically, the Schmidt reaction is the reaction of hydrazoic acid $(\ce{HN3})$ or an alkyl azide $(\ce{R-N3})$ with a carbonyl compound including a carboxylic acid, a ketone, or an aldehyde, often in the presence of a Brønsted or Lewis acid. Further, the reaction of $\ce{HN3}$ or $\ce{R-N3}$ with an alkene or an alcohol is also called the Schmidt reaction (Ref.1):

[image: Schmidt reaction]

As shown by the products, all of these reactions have undergone a rearrangement to give perticular product except for the nitrile formation from the aldehyde.

The mechanism of the Schmidt reaction is well understood (Ref.2). In the case of a carboxylic acid reaction with hydrazoic acid, the initial formation of an acylium ion is followed by the addition of $\ce{HN3}$ to form an acyl azide intermediate. The possible migration of alkyl or acyl group produces the corresponding isocyanate, which undergoes hydrolysis to yield an amine (not an amide) and carbon dioxide:

[image: The mechanism of the Schmidt reaction]

---

**References:**

1. Karl Friedrich Schmidt, “Process of making derivatives of hypothetical imines including amines and their substitution products,” *U.S. Patent* 1,564,631, 1925.
2. Peter A. S. Smith, “The Schmidt Reaction: Experimental Conditions and Mechanism,” *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1948**, *70(1)*, 320–323 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01181a098).